# SSHI circuit on LTSpice

Tags: circuit-design, ltspice, energy, piezo, energy-harvesting

I've been trying to get an SSHI circuit running on LTspice for several days now (see below schematic). My problem is the following: the simulation (.tran) stops after a hundred milliseconds. Being a beginner, I don't know what to do about this problem.

Thank you in advance for your help.

[image: SSHI circuit]

[image: voltage on the source and on C3]

Comment: You're having convergence issues, presumably.

Comment: @Hearth What are convergence issues ?

Comment: The solver is having trouble converging on a solution. It's a simulation problem, not a problem with the circuit. I'm not awake enough to help figure out how to fix it though. Incidentally, just out of curiosity, why do you have all your wires going past the terminals of your devices?

Comment: @Hearth I didn't pay attention to it but I think it doesn't affect the circuit (as I said, i'm still very new to this)

Comment: That doesn't look like a pukka SSHI circuit to me - where did it come from?

Comment: @Andy aka Page 24 : https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/20/12/3512/pdf

Comment: Well, I stand corrected.

Comment: @Julien Yeah, it shouldn't affect anything--I've just seen a bunch of people do it and I'm starting to wonder why.

Comment: A couple quick comments.  You're missing the `Rp` for the current source.  Your PNPs are specified as 2N3906, but you left the NPNs as default.  I would select 2N3904 for them so you don't leave them as default.  Doesn't hurt to select 1N4148 for the diodes too so the solver doesn't have to deal with zero series resistance and zero junction capacitance.  Maybe also right-click L1 and add more equivalent series resistance.

Comment: @Ste Kulov It worked. Thank you very much you are a genius.

Comment: @Julien Oh, cool.  Do you know what specifically did the trick, or did you just change a bunch of things at once?  What inductor series resistance did you end up using?

Comment: @Ste Kulov I added up a 100 Ohm resistance, changed the NPN transistors and diodes

Comment: @Julien  Gotcha.  Thanks for the feedback!